# Extending Auth cookie expiry date to keep users logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I would like to keep users logged in if they continue to use the website. Setting the timeout in web.config only sets the expiry date from when they last logged in -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/User/SignIn" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="43200" defaultUrl="~/account/" />
</authentication>
```

So in 30 days they will be automatically logged out regardless if they use the website everyday. Is resetting the expiry date on every page load the correct solution, like so -

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];
if (!cookie.Value.IsEmpty())
{
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(43200));
    Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the sliding expiration property to true so you shouldn't need to do anything except wait 15 days to test.

> Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the timeout interval has elapsed.

the above is from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration?view=netframework-4.7.2).

The expiration won't be reset even if you user is on constantly until at least half of the timeout value has expired so in your case it won't look like it's working until you pass day 15.

Try it with a few hours and test to see if it is working, or have you tried already and it is failing to reset?

Just a side note but please carefully consider the security of your website, setting such a long time out with sliding expiration could potentailly pose much more of a security than if you were to be stricter with control. For example let it expire after 30 days so they must reauthenticate or reduce the timeout to a day or two. From OWASPs secure coding guidelines they suggest

> Establish a session inactivity timeout that is as short as possible, based on balancing risk and business functional requirements. In most cases it should be no more than several hours.

Comment: Thanks Mike I didn't know that, I will test it with a shorter time and consider the potential security issues.